# Spring Web Service Error : 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, rest

Here I have written this code for a `rest web service` in Spring Controllor Class  . After build the project I try to use this `service` using a `Restful-Client`

RestService Code :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl/{prm_passPhraseCode}/{prm_email}", method= RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody User sendResetLink(@PathVariable("prm_passPhraseCode") String prm_sPassPhrase, @PathVariable("prm_email") String prm_sEmail , HttpServletRequest prm_ObjRequest, HttpServletResponse prm_ObjResponse){

......
..... //some more logical Code.

return new User(); //just dummy object for reference.
}
```

Here how I tried to access the Url. I have selected the method type as `post`. 
I have also added two headers

1. `Content-Type : application/json`
2. `Accept : application/json`

URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/webservice.staff.backend/someurl/23812397997713/kumarvikrant625@gmail.com

Although all my other Rest services urls either it is `GET` or `POST` are working fine. 
I have also try by change the `method = RequestMethod.GET` but still get the same error.

**Error** :-

```
Status Code 406 : The resource identified by this request is only capable of 
generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

please help if any one have a Idea.

Comment: Seems sendResetPasswordLink is not reflected in the request mapping

Comment: what did you mean by not reflected ?? didn't get you actually ..@Benchik

Comment: like
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl/sendResetPasswordLink/{prm_passPhraseCode}/{prm_email}"

Answer (score 0):

your Url isn't mapped correctly, you are missing `sendResetPasswordLink`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl/sendResetPasswordLink/{prm_passPhraseCode}/{prm_email}", method= RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Sorry . I have updated the url that i hit using rest-Client. Now say

Comment: if you still have the same error, yous shoul check other mapped url's and look if there is a conflict between them

Comment: I am sure there is no such `url` exists to my local because `/someurl` is uniquely identified in that controllor class. Thanks but still totally absurd @Rafik

Answer (score -1):

Try this.. May be it can work...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someurl/{prm_passPhraseCode}/{prm_email}",headers="Accept=*/*", method= RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: already tried this trick but didn't get the solution @Md shifattul